# unable to start database after server restart

Tags: database, vertica

I'm unable to start databases when the server reboots. I have only one node setup in vertica installation. I see that whenever the server reboots and when I try to start a database from adminTools, atleast once I get the following messages: -

> ****** Starting database: revgauge_demo * Starting nodes: v_revgauge_demo_node0001 (127.0.0.1) Starting Vertica on all nodes.
>   Please wait, databases with large catalog may take a while to
>   initialize. Node Status: v_revgauge_demo_node0001: (DOWN) Node Status:
>   v_revgauge_demo_node0001: (DOWN) Node Status:
>   v_revgauge_demo_node0001: (DOWN) Node Status:
>   v_revgauge_demo_node0001: (DOWN) Node Status:
>   v_revgauge_demo_node0001: (DOWN) Node Status:
>   v_revgauge_demo_node0001: (DOWN) Node Status:
>   v_revgauge_demo_node0001: (DOWN) Node Status:
>   v_revgauge_demo_node0001: (DOWN) Node Status:
>   v_revgauge_demo_node0001: (DOWN) Node Status:
>   v_revgauge_demo_node0001: (DOWN) Error starting database, no nodes are
>   up Press RETURN to continue*

After pressing Enter/Return, I get the following message:-

> Database startup failed. Too many nodes having invalid/ missing last good epoch values to continue. Run diagnostics and contact Vertica 
>   Technical Support.

I use DbVisualizer to query the database and noticed when DbVisualizer is open, then also I get the above error message. I have to close DbVisualizer and then try again or sometimes the database starts after a delay without any problem. Else sometimes I have to kill the 2 processes for the database and try starting the database again and then it starts. Can anyone explain this problem as to why it happens? And what could be the solution other than closing DbVisualizer or killing the process and retrying?

Comment: Look for the dbLog and back trace in your catalog directory to see if any messages are there to lead you in the right direction. Also make sure that your ulimits are set high enough (ulimit -a, especially the open files).  You might have to go back to a previous epoch if there were some corruption.